# What replaced DSA.MSC in Windows Server 2008?

Tags: windows-server-2008, active-directory

I occasionally need to set up domain accounts, and knew how to do this using DSA.msc in Win2003.  However one of the servers I'm working with is Win2008, so I keep having to RDP into another server just to set up the domain account for a new FTP user.  I can't seem to find any replacement for DSA...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

dsa.msc still very much exists in 2008 and 2008 R2.  It gets installed automatically on machines that have the Active Directory Domain Services role installed.  For machines that aren't running the AD DS role, you just have to install it.

- Open Server Manager, go to the Features section
- Add Features
- Remote Server Administration Tools - Role Administration Tools - Active Directory Domain Services Tools - Active Directory Domain Controller Tools
- Next, Finish, etc

You can also get the snap-ins for non-Server OSes with [RSAT](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=7d2f6ad7-656b-4313-a005-4e344e43997d&displaylang=en) (Remote Server Administration Tools).

Comment: Active Directory Domain Services Tools is not an option there...  Downloading RSAT though, that may be what I need.

Comment: FYI, seems a restart is needed after adding features, sigh.

Answer (score 9):

An elaboration on Ryan's answer, due to Telos' feedback.

- Server Manager
- Features
- Add Feature
- Remote Server Administration Tools
- AD DS and AD LDS Tools
- AD DS Tools
- AD DS Snap-Ins and Command-Line Tools

The description for this entry says it includes Active Directory Users and Computer, Active Directory Domains and Trusts, Active Directory Sites and Services, and other tools.

Once added, I was immediately able to go to start -> run -> dsa.msc, and it launched, with no reboot needed.